# Why is my Windsor Implicit Delegate Factory Registration not working?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am trying to get this to work - but I must be missing something
http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-delegate-based-factories.ashx#Registering_factories_implicitly_1

Can anyone spot it?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {

    [TestMethod]
    public void DelegateFactoryTest() {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<AComponent>().LifeStyle.Transient,
            Component.For<IAService>().ImplementedBy<AService>().LifeStyle.Transient
            );

        var comp = container.Resolve<AComponent>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(comp);
        Assert.IsNotNull(comp.GetService());
    }

    class AComponent {
        readonly Func<IAService> _serviceDelegate;

        public AComponent(Func<IAService> serviceDelegate) {
            _serviceDelegate = serviceDelegate;
        }

        public IAService GetService() {
            return _serviceDelegate();
        }
    }

    interface IAService { }

    class AService : IAService { }
}
```

get the following error

Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: Can't create component 'Sandbox.Windsor.Tests.UnitTest1+AComponent' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
'Sandbox.Windsor.Tests.UnitTest1+AComponent' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'System.Func`1[[Sandbox.Windsor.Tests.UnitTest1+IAService, Sandbox.Windsor.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

if I explicitly register, all is well

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<AComponent>().LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<IAService>().ImplementedBy<AService>().LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<Func<IAService>>().Instance(()=>new AService()).LifeStyle.Transient
);
```

Comment: There should be additional information about which exact dependencies are needed. Maybe there's more to the error ?

Comment: yes, it says it needs what I am trying to get for free - added to the error

Comment: try swapping component.for definitions. First register IAservice, then AComponent.

Comment: these objects are not created at time of registration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing `TypedFactoryFacility`.

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>()
```

Comment: thanks, you're right, but also the nested classes in the example must be public